# How can i discover that object is attached to specific Object Context?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, orm

if i have 2 objectContexts for the same model each one hold some objects..

How can i find that object is attached to specific Object Context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one solution by check the object With ObjectStateManager like this :

```
bool isPresent = objectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(((IEntityWithKey)order).EntityKey, out stateEntry);
if (isPresent)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The entity was found");
}
```

is this will work ***always*** fine?